# JS difficulty to document.getElements and output HTML

Tags: javascript, html, outerhtml

I'm trying to output some existing HTML code later in the HTML document. I can't change the HTML code to output and only have JS to do so. 
The relevant code is a unordered list with a class used for other tags:

```
<ul class="styling">...
```

The JS code

```
var AllUl=document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
var AdminUL=AllUl.getElementsByClassName("styling");
var AdminHTML=AdminUL.outerHTML;
```

Everything should be visible and editable here http://jsfiddle.net/fGF7g/3/

Sorry if I have obvious errors, I'm a JS beginner.

Answer (score 4):

[getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName) returns a list of elements with the given tag name, so you should do like:

```
var AllUl=document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
for(var i = 0; i < AllUl.length; i++ ) {
   var AdminUL=AllUl[i].getElementsByClassName("styling");
}
```

Comment: Thx Sudhir (and scrblnrd3). I tried that and the second step seems now ok: http://jsfiddle.net/fGF7g/4/ I'm still unable to do the output of AdminUL as HTML (third step).

Comment: @ChrisR getElementsByClassName also returns set of elements that have the given class name, so you need to loop in for that as well.. see:: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName

Comment: Thx again. I need to retry and understand this another time as it is late here now...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `document.getElementsByTagName` and `AllUL.getElementsByclassName` return arrays. To fix the problem, you will have to use a for loop to iterate through the elements with that class name, like this

```
var AllUL=document.getElementsByTagName("ul");
for(var i = 0; i < AllUL.length; ++i) {
   var AdminUL=AllUL[i].getElementsByClassName("styling");
}
```